# Not able to search data based on Id field of mongo document from nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get the document details based on its id as given below. But, i am not getting any data except an empty array. Further debugging of the code is pointing to parsing issue with JSON.parse(query) statement in below code. Unable to figure out why it is not parsing the object properly.

```
var table = dbase.collection(name);
        var qfld = JSON.parse(fields);      
        var qobj = JSON.parse(query);
        console.log('query : ' + query + ' and fileds ' + fields + ' qid ' + qobj._id + ' device id ' + qobj.deviceid);
        table.find(qobj,qfld).toArray(function(err,result){
            if (err) reject(err);
            else
                resolve(result);
        });
```

I am trying to send query object to the above function as follows where ccaid is in the form "5486ab....ce6".

```
var ccid = new require('mongodb').ObjectID(ccaid);
query = '{\"_id\": '+ ccid + '};
```

Comment: check your quotes on this. Doesn't look right '{\"_id\": '+ ccid + '}; (You don't end with a quote, you end with a bracket.)

Comment: can you post a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: I am sorry, the string is like this  '{\"_id\": '+ ccid + '}'; and the document is like below

Comment: try this:    var qobj = { _id: ccid };

Comment: document is {"_id":ObjectId("5864ad6db887af0a1869c5a6"),"city":"Hyderabad"}

Comment: Tried felix's suggestion, but not working, the query string is being formed as {_id:5864ad6...c5a6} - and it is not like {_id:ObjectId("5864....c5a6"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
var table = dbase.collection(name);
var qfld = JSON.parse(fields); 

var ccid = new require('mongodb').ObjectID(ccaid);     
var qobj = {_id: ccaid };
console.log('query : ' + JSON.stringify(qobj) + ' and fileds ' + fields + ' qid ' + qobj._id + ' device id ' + qobj.deviceid);
table.find(qobj,qfld).toArray(function(err,result){
      if (err) 
         reject(err);
      else
         resolve(result);
 });
```